# Std on dataframe column error IndexEngine

Tags: python, pandas, compiler-errors

I have few CSV files which have loading as

```
dataframe = pandas.concat (pandas.read_csv (name) for name in list)
```

where list is list of data files.

Which have following columns:

```
Date  Close/Last    Volume    Open    High    Low
```

I want to calculate std on open and Close/Last columns.

I tried

`std = dataframe.loc[:,"Open"].std(axis = 0, skipna = True)`

But got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/saurabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Open'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download.py", line 9, in <module>
    analysis.simulateTicker("aapl")
  File "/play/downlaod/analysis.py", line 5, in simulateTicker
    std = dataframe.loc[:,"Open"].std(axis = 0, skipna = True)
  File "/home/saurabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1418, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "/home/saurabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 805, in _getitem_tuple
    return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
  File "/home/saurabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 929, in _getitem_lowerdim
    section = self._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
  File "/home/saurabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1850, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
  File "/home/saurabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 160, in _get_label
    return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis)
  File "/home/saurabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3729, in xs
    return self[key]
  File "/home/saurabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2980, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/home/saurabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2899, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: could you show what `dataframe` looks like?

Comment: Date  Close/Last     Volume       Open      High         Low
0    03/20/2020     $229.24  100423300    $247.18   $251.83        $228
1    03/19/2020     $244.78   67964260   $247.385   $252.84     $242.61
2    03/18/2020     $246.67   75058410    $239.77      $250     $237.12
3    03/17/2020     $252.86   81013970    $247.51   $257.61      $238.4
4    03/16/2020     $242.21   80605870    $241.95   $259.08        $240

Comment: what happens when you just use `dataframe["Open"].std()` ?

Comment: and can I see the rest of the error message?  I think you clipped off the exception at the end.

Comment: @logCopy

   std = dataframe["Open"].std(axis = 0, skipna = True)
  File "/home/saurabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2980, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/home/saurabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2899, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

Comment: @LogCopy I edited my question and added complete stack

Comment: It says that you're getting a `KeyError`, which means that "Open" does not exist in your dataframe as a column.  Could you attach a picture of `dataframe.head()`?  Might be an issue with the formatting.

Comment: #LogCopy strange it printed five row:
         Date  Close/Last     Volume       Open      High       Low
0  03/20/2020     $229.24  100423300    $247.18   $251.83      $228
1  03/19/2020     $244.78   67964260   $247.385   $252.84   $242.61
2  03/18/2020     $246.67   75058410    $239.77      $250   $237.12
3  03/17/2020     $252.86   81013970    $247.51   $257.61    $238.4
4  03/16/2020     $242.21   80605870    $241.95   $259.08      $240

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210198/discussion-between-logcapy-and-crazyc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `Open` column has an extra space there at the beginning.  Try

`std = dataframe.loc[:," Open"].std(axis = 0, skipna = True)`

Comment: You are correct. 
print(dataframe[" Open"])
shown data but now getting which is i think type conversion. 
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' $247.18'

Comment: This is because '$247.18' is read as a string.  Try to cast it as a float first:

```dataframe[" Open"] = dataframe["  Open"].replace('[\$,]', '', regex=True).astype(float)```